# Symfony2 InvalidArgumentException in routing.yml

Tags: symfony, routes

i have created these routes in `src/Dive/LogbookBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`:

```
login: 
   path:    /
   defaults: { _controller: DiveLogbookBundle:Security:login }

login_check: 
   pattern:   /login_check

random:
   path: /random/{limit}
   defaults: { _controller: DiveLogbookBundle:Random:index }
```

but when i access the webpage it returns an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The definition of "login" in "/var/www/src/Dive/LogbookBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" must be a YAML array.' in /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php:190
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(88): Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->validate(NULL, 'login', '/var/www/src/Di...') 
#1 /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php(106): Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/var/www/src/Di...', NULL) 
#2 /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(155): Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('@DiveLogbookBun...', NULL, false, '/var/www/app/co...')
#3 /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(91): Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImport(Object(Symfony in /var/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2986
```

Does anyone know what causes this problem and how can i resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure that your routing definitions are formatted properly.  you should not use tab characters to indent (use 4 spaces instead).  YAML also uses indentation to define arrays, so if your YAML isn't indented properly, you will get an error

Comment: @Sehael, thanks i did had a tab in the `login` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the formatting of your `routing.yml`. YAML has quite strict standards regarding whitespace, and should not contain any tab characters - all indentation must be done with spaces. Make sure you have indented everything correctly and maybe do a search and replace for `\t` if your code editor allows.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I had a tab inside the `login` route.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: the linter can be used to spot the problem immediately `php app/console lint:yaml <file_to_lint.yml>`